# Download Excel package as file without creating a physical file?

Tags: c#, excel, file, filestream, epplus

I am looking for code to download a file to a clients pc, I would like to not store the physical file and worry about deleting it at a later stage.
At the moment i create a physical file and then download it, the file name remains the same so it replaces the previous one. My concern is that multiple users might end up overwriting the file when both trying to download at the same time.

Here is some of my code:

```
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
{
   // edit cells and add details into the excel file

   //Here u save the file, i would like this to be a stream
   using (FileStream aFile = new FileStream(MapPath("../../template/LeadsExport.xlsx"), FileMode.Create))
   {
      try
      {
         package.SaveAs(aFile);
         aFile.Close();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
      }
    }
      // Here i download the file, i would like this to use a stream and not a physical file
      FileInfo file = new FileInfo(MapPath("../../template/LeadsExport.xlsx"));
      Response.Clear();
      Response.ClearHeaders();
      Response.ClearContent();
      Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
      Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
      Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
      Response.Flush();
      Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);
      Response.End();

}
```

I would like to have the package saved into a file stream and not a physical file and then some way to download it.

Comment: Instead of `FileStream`, use `MemoryStream`. It's not clear what both code blocks have to do with each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have half the answer, in both code and in your question-text itself. Instead of writing the Excel package to disk, write it to the response stream.

```
Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=LeadsExport.xlsx");
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";                    
Response.BinaryWrite(package.GetAsByteArray());
Response.End();
```

Comment: Downloads the file, but its content is blank. just the template i started with before i edited it

Comment: You might want to make a new question about that, as it seems like it's a different issue altogether.

Comment: I think this is correct, think is a problem somewhere else, let me fix it and i will mark this as correct when i'm done. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Thanks, The problem was else where. This works perfectly, thanks so much for the help.